# Read & parse unicode json data not work in IE and FF

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, unicode

I want to read json data file from another domain (CORS).
This file contain Unicode data, Like:

```
{"id":21,"name":"پرسپولیس تهران"}
```

I used JQuery Ajax function like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: SDomain + 'XML/TeamXMLCache/' + filename + '.json',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    success: parseXml,
    error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And this work me fine in Chrome 39 but not working in IE11 & FF32.

In IE I get **parsererror** error.

For more information:

- responseText is:`{"id":21,"name":"~13~HD3 *G1'F"}`
- readyState:4
- statusText:"OK"
- status:200

And finally my config file is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So please tell me why? I'm not a beginner!

Real sample is:
[My real sample](http://www.persiangulfcup.org/Teams/21/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%BE%D9%88%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%B3-%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/)

Comment: The data does not seem to be UTF-8 encoded, rather it is UTF-16LE encoded. So you will need to change the encoding of the data or you will need to change the response headers to indicate UTF-16LE encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I loaded http://static.persiangulfcup.org/XML/TeamXMLCache/21-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%BE%D9%88%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%B3-%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86.json?_=1417448329770 with Firefox in a browser window, it displayed the JSON fine but indicated in document info that the encoding is UTF-16LE and not UTF-8 as indicated in your post. Based on that I think you need to make sure the data is correctly UTF-8 encoded or you need to make sure it is served with a content type header indicating the real encoding.

Comment: Please see the Link in end of question

Comment: Does the runnable snippet I posted not work for you in your browsers? Or does it not work when you try the code on your server with your data?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martin for correct answer.

Problem was when I create my json file. I used `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` instead of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` to save json files in my server.

But my new question is how do you understand that my file is under UTF-16LE format?
Please post as answer then I can mark it as correct answer.