# jQuery.getJSON not working in IE with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer

I am trying to call jQuery.getJSON but it is not returning me anydata in **Internet Explorer**. The below code works in all browsers and returns the data except for IE.

```
jQuery.getJSON("/samplejsonfile.json",function(data){
console.log('inside');  //For IE the control never reaches here
camData = data;
})
```

The json file is having special unicode characters and that is the reason the getJSON method is not working in IE. Below is my sample JSON file:

```
{"id":74112,"title":"Flø","cameratype":"0"}
```

Is there any way I can make this working and get IE to return the data correctly?

Comment: What version of IE? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570757/how-to-correct-character-encoding-in-ie8-native-json says this doesn't work in IE8, but should work in IE9.

Comment: the version is IE 11. This issue doesn't exist in Edge.

Comment: Is this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225567/read-parse-unicode-json-data-not-work-in-ie-and-ff

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: yes , the error function returns the below error. And this error is because of the special character in the json:            {description: "Expected '}'", message: "Expected '}'", name: "SyntaxError", number: -2146827279, stack: "SyntaxError..."}

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ajax instead. It has helped me to solved similar problem. I have read somewhere getJSON tends to cache data in IE.